# Save elements in html form

Tags: html, forms

I have a list of items. When I select one of them, this element remains in input form. How can I add or remove other elements? For example I select Internet Explorer and it is remains in the input, after that I select Firefox, and it is added separated by commas or remove as adding or removing tags in this forum.

```
 <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```

How to solve it?

Comment: with some javascript

Comment: @MisterJojo, could you please show it on my sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Javascript or any library.

I am attaching how you can do with select2:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

$("#browsers").select2();

  <select id="browsers" name="browser" multiple>
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </select>
```

Comment: make sure you have JQUERY library to because it does work : For more take a look on the documentation of SELECT2 https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage